# Prove that running time T(n)=$(n + a)^b$ is $O(n^b)$ with a and b > 0

Tags: notation, asymptotics, computational-complexity, binomial-theorem

[Image of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucZSs.jpg)

I'm studying asymptotic notation, but i'm stuck at this question, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$T(n)=(n + a)^b \leqslant (n + n)^b=2^bn^b$$
when $\lfloor a \rfloor+1<n$, so we can take any $C\geqslant n^b$ and $N=\lfloor a \rfloor+1$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of $O(n^b)$ we need to show that it exists a constant $C>0$ such that $(n+a)^b \leq Cn^b$. (There should be absolute values, but assuming $a\geq0$ you don't need them; if $a<0$ the problem is trivial with $C=1$)

Now, can $f$ defined as $f(x) = \frac{(x+a)^b}{x^b}$ be unbounded as a function from $[1,+\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: a and b are bigger then 0

Comment: and the function needs to be on the integers

Comment: Well, if you show that it is bounded on reals bigger (or equal) than $1$, you show that it is also bounded on positive integers

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: how do you do what? show that it is bounded on $[1,\infty)$ or show that the implication in the last comment is true?

Comment: For the first one, ever heard of Weierstass theorem on compact sets?

Comment: I actually cant use any type of limits, i think i need to prove it using newtons binom, like: $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{b}\binom{b}{i}.n^i.a^{b-i}$

Comment: well, then you can use that $n^i \leq n^b$ and thus $(n+a)^b \leq n^b \cdot \sum\limits_{i=0}^b \binom{b}{i} a^{b-i}$

Comment: How do i use it to prove this: $(n + a)^b = O(n^b)$, then $\exists (c,n_0)$ | $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{b}\binom{b}{i}.n^i.a^{b-i}$ $\leq c.n^b$  To $n \geq n_{0}$?

Comment: $n_0=1$ and $c = \sum\limits_{i=0}^b \binom{b}{i}a^{b-i}$

Answer (score 0):

To prove it, show:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+a)^b}{n^b} = 1
$$

Comment: I cant use limits

Comment: Such limitations ("I can't use limits") ... this is one reason questions should have more information than "I am stuck".